# Possibly empty Foreign Key in forms.py leads to not null constraint fail

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a class customer, that holds some information, for example a contact person for this customer. This field can be empty and the model shows simplified as follows:

**model**:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Company name', max_length=120)
    contact_persons = models.ForeignKey(ContactPerson, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The corresponding **view**:

```
class CustomerCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Customer
    template_name ="gap/add_customer.html"
    form_class = CustomerModelForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('customer-list')
```

And the **form**:

```
class CustomerModelForm(ModelForm):
    required_css_class = "required"
    
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = "__all__"
```

Now, when I enter the data I always end up in a `NOT NULL constraint failed: gap_customer.contact_persons_id`. How would I solve this?

Comment: did you ran migrations properly?

Comment: you were right, that did the trick :) Thanks!